Flutter project opens the emulator, but it doesn't load the application; instead, it opens a new device
I created a project with Flutter, but when I 'run,' it opens the device without loading the app. I've tried with other devices, but it never opens the application. I don't understand what's causing this. Can someone please explain how to fix this?"
